# Interaction with multiple charts in a page

Tags: javascript, d3.js, charts, highcharts, fusioncharts

If I have multiple charts, say a stacked bar and a pie chart on my page. I would like to interact (e.g. click) on one of it and see some visual update on the other chart. 
I tried creating them using FusionCharts in the following manner:

```js
FusionCharts.ready(function() {
  var pieChart = new FusionCharts({
    type: 'pie2d',
    renderAt: 'pieContainer',
    width: '400',
    height: '300',
    dataFormat: 'json',
    dataSource: {
      "chart": {
        "caption": "Company Revenue",
        "enableMultiSlicing": "0",
        "bgcolor": "FFFFFF",
        "showvalues": "1",
        "showpercentvalues": "1",
        "showborder": "0",
        "showplotborder": "0",
        "showlegend": "1",
        "legendborder": "0",
        "legendposition": "bottom",
        "enablesmartlabels": "1",
        "use3dlighting": "0",
        "showshadow": "0",
        "legendbgcolor": "#CCCCCC",
        "legendbgalpha": "20",
        "legendborderalpha": "0",
        "legendshadow": "0",
        "legendnumcolumns": "3",
        "palettecolors": "#f8bd19,#e44a00,#008ee4,#33bdda,#6baa01,#583e78"
      },
      "data": [{
        "label": "Services",
        "value": "26"
      }, {
        "label": "Hardware",
        "value": "32"
      }, {
        "label": "Software",
        "value": "42"
      }]
    }
  }).render();

  var stackedBar = new FusionCharts({
    type: 'stackedBar2D',
    renderAt: 'barContainer',
    width: '400',
    height: '300',
    dataFormat: 'json',
    dataSource: {
      "chart": {
        "caption": "Company Revenue",
        "xaxisname": "Month",
        "yaxisname": "Revenue",
        "bgcolor": "FFFFFF",
        "outcnvbasefontcolor": "666666",
        "numberprefix": "$",
        "showvalues": "0",
        "numvdivlines": "10",
        "showalternatevgridcolor": "1",
        "alternatevgridcolor": "e1f5ff",
        "divlinecolor": "e1f5ff",
        "vdivlinecolor": "e1f5ff",
        "basefontcolor": "666666",
        "tooltipbgcolor": "F3F3F3",
        "tooltipbordercolor": "666666",
        "canvasbordercolor": "666666",
        "canvasborderthickness": "1",
        "showplotborder": "1",
        "plotfillalpha": "80",
        "showborder": "0",
        "legendbgcolor": "#CCCCCC",
        "legendbgalpha": "20",
        "legendborderalpha": "0",
        "legendshadow": "0",
        "legendnumcolumns": "3"
      },
      "categories": [{
        "category": [{
          "label": "Jan"
        }, {
          "label": "Feb"
        }, {
          "label": "Mar"
        }, {
          "label": "Apr"
        }, {
          "label": "May"
        }, {
          "label": "Jun"
        }, {
          "label": "Jul"
        }, {
          "label": "Aug"
        }, {
          "label": "Sep"
        }, {
          "label": "Oct"
        }, {
          "label": "Nov"
        }, {
          "label": "Dec"
        }]
      }],
      "dataset": [{
        "seriesname": "Product A",
        "data": [{
          "value": "27400"
        }, {
          "value": "29800"
        }, {
          "value": "25800"
        }, {
          "value": "26800"
        }, {
          "value": "29600"
        }, {
          "value": "32600"
        }, {
          "value": "31800"
        }, {
          "value": "36700"
        }, {
          "value": "29700"
        }, {
          "value": "31900"
        }, {
          "value": "34800"
        }, {
          "value": "24800"
        }]
      }, {
        "seriesname": "Product B",
        "data": [{
          "value": "10000"
        }, {
          "value": "11500"
        }, {
          "value": "12500"
        }, {
          "value": "15000"
        }, {
          "value": "11000"
        }, {
          "value": "9800"
        }, {
          "value": "11800"
        }, {
          "value": "19700"
        }, {
          "value": "21700"
        }, {
          "value": "21900"
        }, {
          "value": "22900"
        }, {
          "value": "20800"
        }]
      }],
      "trendlines": [{
        "line": [{
          "startvalue": "42000",
          "color": "91C728",
          "displayvalue": "Target",
          "showontop": "1"
        }]
      }],
      "styles": {
        "definition": [{
          "name": "CanvasAnim",
          "type": "animation",
          "param": "_xScale",
          "start": "0",
          "duration": "1"
        }],
        "application": [{
          "toobject": "Canvas",
          "styles": "CanvasAnim"
        }]
      }
    }
  }).render();
});
```

```html
<script src="http://static.fusioncharts.com/code/latest/fusioncharts.js"></script>
<div>
  <span id="barContainer">FusionCharts XT will load here!</span>
  <span id="pieContainer">FusionCharts XT will load here!</span>
</div>
```

Now how to update the other chart on interacting one of the chart? Say by clicking or hovering plots on one of the chart, has its visual update in another chart.

**Note: ** The data is not relevant in this case. Only the chart to chart interactivity needs to be established. There is no restriction on JS library being used and can be entirely based on the responder choice.Any help is highly appreciable.

Answer (score 1):

With highcharts, you could override the click function, then update whichever properties you want.

See: http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#chart.events

Answer (score 0):

I do not know how it is with FusionCharts, although I think syncing data between different type of charts should be possible, but I was using a lot amCharts and if you have no restriction on library then I put this quick tips link to show you what you can fairly quickly implement there.

http://www.amcharts.com/tips/automatically-syncing-pie-chart-data-column-chart-hover/

Answer (score 0):

You can use drill down to detailed linked charts that show data at different levels of detail.

Using linked charts, you can create unlimited levels of drill-down charts with a single data source.

You can drill-down into the descendant charts by clicking the data plot items of the parent chart. The descendant charts can either replace the parent chart, with an option to drill-up, or they can open in new windows or frames.

To know more about this feature please refer - https://www.fusioncharts.com/dev/chart-guide/chart-configurations/drill-down#chart-links-linked-charts-

```
    FusionCharts.ready(function() {
  var satisfactionChart = new FusionCharts({
    type: 'column2d',
    renderAt: 'chart-container',
    width: '400',
    height: '300',
    dataFormat: 'json',
    dataSource: {
      "chart": {
        "caption": "Top 3 Juice Flavors",
        "subcaption": "Last year",
        "xaxisName": "Flavor",
        "yaxisName": "Amount (In USD)",
        "numberPrefix": "$",
        "theme": "fusion"
      },
      "data": [{
        "label": "Apple",
        "value": "810000",
        "link": "newchart-xml-apple"
      }, {
        "label": "Cranberry",
        "value": "620000",
        "link": "newchart-xml-cranberry"
      }, {
        "label": "Grapes",
        "value": "350000",
        "link": "newchart-xml-grapes"
      }],
      "linkeddata": [{
        "id": "apple",
        "linkedchart": {
          "chart": {
            "caption": "Apple Juice - Quarterly Sales",
            "subcaption": "Last year",
            "xaxisname": "Quarter",
            "yaxisname": "Amount (In USD)",
            "numberprefix": "$",
            "theme": "fusion",
            "rotateValues": "0"
          },
          "data": [{
            "label": "Q1",
            "value": "157000"
          }, {
            "label": "Q2",
            "value": "172000"
          }, {
            "label": "Q3",
            "value": "206000"
          }, {
            "label": "Q4",
            "value": "275000",
            "rotateValues": "0"
          }]
        }
      }, {
        "id": "cranberry",
        "linkedchart": {
          "chart": {
            "caption": "Cranberry Juice - Quarterly Sales",
            "subcaption": "Last year",
            "xaxisname": "Quarter",
            "yaxisname": "Amount (In USD)",
            "numberprefix": "$",
            "theme": "fusion",
            "rotateValues": "0"
          },
          "data": [{
            "label": "Q1",
            "value": "102000"
          }, {
            "label": "Q2",
            "value": "142000"
          }, {
            "label": "Q3",
            "value": "187000"
          }, {
            "label": "Q4",
            "value": "189000"
          }]
        }
      }, {
        "id": "grapes",
        "linkedchart": {
          "chart": {
            "caption": "Grape Juice - Quarterly Sales",
            "subcaption": "Last year",
            "xaxisname": "Quarter",
            "yaxisname": "Amount (In USD)",
            "numberprefix": "$",
            "theme": "fusion",
            "rotateValues": "0"
          },
          "data": [{
            "label": "Q1",
            "value": "45000"
          }, {
            "label": "Q2",
            "value": "72000"
          }, {
            "label": "Q3",
            "value": "95000"
          }, {
            "label": "Q4",
            "value": "108000"
          }]
        }
      }]
    }
  });
    
  satisfactionChart.render();
  satisfactionChart.configureLink({
    type: 'pie2d',
    width: '80%', 
   });

});
```

Here is the Demo - https://jsfiddle.net/8j5qoayg/